# Changes to DOM objects are lost after partial update

Tags: xpages

On a page I have some fields that I want to be "readonly" *(in my meaning they can't be accessed but they will store values, read earlier question in this matter if issues...)*.

I use a client JS setting these attributes on page load:

```
$(".readonly").attr('readonly', true);
```

If I have a partial update on any of these fields the attribute is lost and the field is accessible.

What is the best practice to overcome this and make it work?

Comment: I think this is misunderstanding of partial refresh. Partially refreshed region is always replaced with freshly rendered content, no DOM part is preserved. Works as designed.

Comment: There is no misunderstanding, I just wanted to know how to overcome this issue…  Can't see why this question was down-voted…

Comment: If the server is never told that the attribute changed, then the server will send back the previous state of the component... basic principle of XPage development. Set the readonly attribute server-side, not client-side; since you're setting this attribute on page load anyway, this would be a better approach.

Comment: On a side note: If you tune your application for performance you might want to consider dojo instead of jQuery since the XPages runtime can optimize the js for it. It doesn't for jquery.

Comment: You might want to consider rethinking your approach: a flick of a button in the Firefox web developer toolbar makes that field writeable by the user. So the best practise: look for an approach that doesn't depend on read-only fields. Labels would do and any item manipulation can be done in querysave (In case you claim "there is no other way"... I'll bet a Starbucks beverage against it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with *jjtbsomhorst* on using `onComplete` event. But another alternative could be setting the `readonly` property via code like this:

```
var textField:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputText = getComponent("inputText1");
var readOnlyAttr:com.ibm.xsp.complex.Attr = new com.ibm.xsp.complex.Attr("readonly", "readonly");
var list:java.util.ArrayList = new java.util.ArrayList();
list.add(readOnlyAttr);
textField.setAttrs(list);
```

You could call this on the `afterPageLoad` event of the XPage. But I really don't know whether this would be the best way to about!

Answer (score 3):

Every partial refresh has a oncomplete method bound to it. What you could do is add code to the oncomplete method so the item is being set readonly again. Another, better,  approach would be not to change the attribute clientside but to have hidden fields which are used to store the data.

When you have an event bound to for instance an Link control you can change the oncomplete code by clicking in your source pane on the event tag. When you browse the events section in the properties pane you will see the onComplete, onError, onStart properties. You can add your own clientside script in these properties.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: OK, thanks. I assume you're referring to hijacking the partial refresh client side so I can trap the onComplete?

Comment: I tried to hijack the partial and it worked however I'll continue to try a more solid approach… Thx

Answer (score 1):

Before trying to overcome the "problem" You shoud try to understand what exactly partial refresh do and where the state of application is kept.

Unfortunately partial refresh is replacing current html content (or rather part of it) with a newly created one and only form fields that has backing controls will keep state.

I suggest You should try setting readonly property on controls which You would like to make readonly (if there is some logic here You can always use ssjs).

Optionally You can try to preserve the state on the client side by using csjs global variables but this is rather hard to manage.

And one more thing - try to use the technology to solve the problem(xpages) and try not to hack Your way through with use of stuff that You accidentally know (jquery).

Comment: I Do understand how the partial refresh is working, I'm just struggling with the readonly attribute of my fields. In a previous question posted we have debated my solution. Readonly attribute on a field will not save it to the database so therefor I want it to be readonly set by client because my users want the information displayed and saved but they are not allowed to type anything in those fields. Trying to adhere to the technique is always the best approach but when the technique lacks, the "hacking" as you said is applicable, that is what we do all the time

Comment: Sorry, I paid too much attention to the second part of Your question and have taken it out of context. I still don't understand why it have to be on the client side.

Comment: You are right, I have moved to a SSJS solution. Wasn't aware of the feature to set the attribute. Thx !